# JQuery Plugin Tutorial - How does the methods other than init access options?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In the [jQuery plugin tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) , how does the other methods like show(), hide() or update() access the options passed in init()? What is the correct way to handle it in init() so other methods can access it?

```
(function( $ ){

  var methods = {
    init : function( options ) { // THIS },
    show : function( ) { // IS   },
    hide : function( ) { // GOOD },
    update : function( content ) { // !!! }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    

  };

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my plugins i always access options using:

```
this.options
```

but... i use a diferent approach...

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("my.plugin", {
        options: {
            op1: "op1"
        },
        _init: function () {

        },
        _create: function () {

        },
        show: function () {
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Is there something special with 'widget'? I have just started trying to create a jQuery plugin and that structure seems new to me. Can you explain why it is structured that way?

Comment: from what i know, this is the way jquery-ui plugins are created, so it must be a good option :) is basicly saves you time and gives you a basic structure for your plugin. ex: the "Method calling logic" is already implemented.
functions starting by '_' are private and can't by called using $('#xpto').myplugin('method').
functions like "_create" and "_init" are called automaticly.

Comment: Is this solution jquery-ui dependent?

Comment: is dependent from jquery.ui.widget witch is included in jquery.ui but you can download it separately.
demo - http://jqueryui.com/demos/widget/
download - http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js
more info - http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget-factory